# VBA Worksheet reference being ignored

Tags: vba, range, worksheet

I have a question that frustrates me for a while now - Why does

```
Worksheets("Machine Layout")
```

code is being ignored in code like like

```
Worksheets("Machine Layout").Cells(16, ActiveCell.Column).Value
```

I keep needing to do

```
Worksheets("Machine Layout").Select
```

before every code like mentioned above.

I have a workbook with 3 distinct worksheets and even that

```
Worksheets("Machine Layout").Select
```

gets ignored sometimes and does not infact select the sheet I need.

What would be a better solution to avoid any such issues when code execution dies because the line

```
Worksheets("Machine Layout").Cells(16, ActiveCell.Column).Value
```

couldn't figure out to select the sheet that's clearly mentioned in it...

Could someone, please, help?

Comment: What do you mean by  'ignored'? `ActiveCell` refers to the currently active cell, which will be on the currently active sheet in the currently active workbook.

Comment: Rather than repeat variants of the same line, it would be useful to post the problem line *in context* so we can see what else is going on while your code is running.  You should almost never need to select a sheet to reference a range on it.  `ActiveCell` is a property of the Application object, but its value may depend on the currently-selected sheet.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think that it would be useful cuz it's basically that line with HUGE amounts of other stuff

Comment: @norie How could I change that? Because my sheets active range I'm working with is dynamic and that column in question might always be different

Comment: OK then maybe explain exactly why you need to use `ActiveCell`?

Comment: My workbook has 3 sheets of which 1 is the main one which I don't use and 2 are symmetrical in a sense. I am adding and deleting and selecting columns to load cell values to userform - work with them and paste them back in their respective place. That place might be in either one of those two sheets where active column might be different and unpredictable which one it will be, you know? I don't understand why that first part of the code doesn't activate the sheet by itself

Comment: You really shouldn't be working with 'active' anything, instead you should be clearly defining and referencing all the objects, e.g. workbooks, worksheets, ranges etc., you are working with.

Comment: I know I should, but it's kinda impossible because the number or columns I may be moving through by selecting them is anywhere from 1 to infinity :D and the column in question may always be different

Comment: It may help to build the range selection directly into your code, instead of relying on a pre-existing selection on one or more sheets.  Then you can have a direct reference to the relevant range(s), instead of using ActiveCell/Selection and needing to activate sheets before you read those Application properties.

Comment: What do you mean by "build the range selection directly into your code,"?

Comment: https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/vba-to-select-range-with-inputbox

Comment: Well this gives me an idea, that I could do an abstract value "Column counter" and use that value as column number. Don't know how to do it yet in a way that would recover after closing and opening the workbook again